# Experiment or simulation to undestand type I and type II errors

Tags: hypothesis-testing, simulation, references, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am studying Type I and Type II errors and basic concepts of testing hypotheses. To better develop my intuition I would like to write a few simple simulations.

What I'm hoping is to get a base simulation going, that I can then tweak to understand this area.

I am not looking for code in a specific language. However, pseudo code would be great, or references to a well documented example.

Thanks.

Comment: A good book on this, at a moderate mathematical level, is [Chihara and Hesterberg](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Statistics-Resampling-Laura-Chihara/dp/1118029852/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1350820311&sr=8-1&keywords=hesterberg)

Answer (score 5):

This would be the most basic procedure behind any such simulation:

**Type I errors:**

1. Have the computer generate a set (of size $n$) of [pseudorandom numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) that conform to a particular distribution (the normal would be most typical).
2. Generate a second identical set (i.e., same distribution, parameters, and size).
3. Conduct a statistical test on these data (as I have described this, a t-test would be appropriate).
4. Store the resulting p-value.
5. Iterate over (repeat) the above procedure many times (e.g., 10k is popular).
6. Determine the proportion of observed p-values fall below your chosen $\alpha$ level (typically .05).
   (Note that this observed proportion ought to be very close to $\alpha$.)

**Type II errors** (modify the above procedure as follows):

For the second step: Generate a second set of pseudorandom numbers that *differ* from the first set in a pre-specified way (typically the mean would differ by some amount).

On the sixth step: the proportion of observed p-values below $\alpha$ will almost certainly differ from $\alpha$ by a large amount.  The observed proportion is an estimate of the [statistical power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power) of your test for that exact situation (i.e., data from those distributions, with those parameters, with those $n$'s).

---

Using simulations in a manner like this to explore properties of tests or situations, or to conduct power analyses is very common.  Moreover, they have been commonly used on this site to demonstrate / explain statistical concepts.  Here are some threads you can explore if you want:

- Here is an example where I used such a simulation to show that power decreases as the two group sizes become increasingly unequal: [How should one interpret the comparison of means from different sample sizes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31326//31330#31330)
- This is a very extensive discussion of using simulations to assess power: [Simulation of logistic regression power analysis - designed experiments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35940//35994#35994).
- A broader discussion of using simulations to understand statistical concepts can be found here: [Using computer simulations to better understand statistical concepts at the graduate level](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38593/).

Answer (score 3):

The most common example is of this kind: take a normal variate, $X_1$, which can be either $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ or $\mathcal{N}(2,1)$. If you build a test accepting $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ when $x_1<1.68$ and rejecting $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ when $x_1>1.68$, it is rather simple to check by simulation that the type I error is $0.05$ and the type II error is $0.37$. For instance,

```
#type I error
x=rnorm(10^3)
sum(x>1.68)/10^3
```

and

```
#type II error
x=rnorm(10^3,2)
sum(x<1.68)/10^3
```

Of course, simulation is not very helpful in this case, where everything can be computed analytically.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Geoff Cumming's "dancing p-values"

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ez4DgdurRPg&feature=plcp

Cummings is the author of "Understanding the new statistics."