# Type 2 error meaning

Tags: statistical-significance

Type I error is when we reject a certain hypothesis that we know is true but the data we had was in an extreme area. 
What is an intuitive explanation of the the type II error and the power function of a hypothesis test

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40868/experiment-or-simulation-to-undestand-type-i-and-type-ii-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type 2 error is the probability of accepting the null hypothesis (H0) given that the alternative hypothesis (HA) is true. For instance, if you have a mean shift in the data, then the probability of detecting this mean shift is 1-Type II error.

For the power function, given a rejection region R for your test, the power function is defined as the probability your observations belongs to the rejection rejoin, thus the power function is :

```
Type I error if H0 is true
1-Type II error if HA is true
```